# python non-negative non-zero lstsq

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

For a project I need to take one array (m) of shape (800,16) containing model results and one array (o) of shape (800) containing observed results and produce an array (c) using the first set of values from non-negative AND non-zero least squares regression on arrays m and o. Currently I am using

```
c = scipy.optimize.nnls(m,o)[0]
```

however some values are 0, which is an issue because later on i take the log of these values.

Does anyone know of a way to do non-negative and non-zero least squares linear regression?

EDIT: Perhaps by setting bounds on the values? (0.01,100) would be desirable bounds in this scenario

Comment: would it work to set all the zero and negative values to NaN (`m[m <= 0] = np.nan`)?

Comment: yes, but the values are 'scaling factors' used to show which part of the model is over/under predicting. Using NaN values after the fact would skew these results

Comment: ‏‏‏maybe you want to choose a very small _epsilon_ value and assign `m[m<=0] = epsilon`?

Comment: I also tried that, however taking the log of the epsilon values produced very large numbers

Comment: Solving the problem on an open interval is not well defined. Think about it: suppose you want to minimize x**2, and the constraint is x > 0.  What is the solution?

Comment: bounds of 0.01,100 would be desirable

Comment: See the answer by @ev-br in the question that this one duplicates.